# AspectJ Before can return from method?

Tags: java, aspectj

Can I return from method with annotation **@Before** in AspectJ.

```
@Before
public void simpleAdvice(JoinPoin joinPoint) {
    if (smth == null)
    /* return for method, which annotated */
}
```

If my question is not fully, please ask me another for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method using the `@Before`  ,  `@After`  ,  `@AfterReturning` , `@AfterThrowing` , `@Around` . But your class can be registered with the `@Aspect` .

Also you need to define the `pointcut` and `joinpoints`.

For **example**,

```
@Before(value="execution(* com.pointel.aop.AopTest.beforeAspect(..))")
public void beforeAdvicing(JoinPoint joinPoint){ 

    String name = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    System.out.println("Name of the method : "+name);

}

@AfterReturning(value="execution(* com.pointel.aop.AopTest.beforeAspect(..))")
public void beforeAdvicing(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object result){ 

    String name = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    System.out.println("Name of the method : "+name);
    System.out.println("Method returned value is : " + result);

}
```

Your **Java** class will be,

```
package com.pointel.aop;

public class AopTest {

    public String beforeAspect( ) {
        return "I am a AopTest";
    }
}
```

That's it.Hope it helps.

Comment: A want exit from method beforeAspect() before execute this method. Can I do it?

Comment: I want, before executing my method, check sessionId from user. If sessionId == null, break from method and don't execute method. And I don't khow how to use @Before-annotation that it can break from method. Are you understand me now?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Aspect
@SuppressAjWarnings({ "adviceDidNotMatch" })
public class TestAspect {
    @Around("execution(@Monitor void *..*.* ())")
    public void aroundMethodWithMonitorAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.err.println("Around - before a()");

        String sessionId = (String) proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];

        if(sessionId != null){
            proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
            System.err.println("Around - after a()");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Around - a() not called");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestAspect().a();
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
    public @interface Monitor {
    }

    @Monitor
    public void a() {
        System.err.println("a()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. It isn't result. Try again. I see you result is "Around - before a()" -> "a()" -> "Around - after a()". But, I want, for instance, in your example, if i have wrong param in a() - method, I get result "Around -before a()" and only this string. Only if i wrong params (for example)

Comment: With JoinPoint.getArgs() you can access on method parameter. If sessionId is null, you don't call JoinPoint.proceed(). I edit my answer to show you an example.